# Jenkins not showing env set in from .bash_profile

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm trying to build via Jenkins but the .bash_profile $PATH additions aren't reflected when built remotely via Jenkins but in the terminal of the same user I can see them.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue ? How did you source bash_profile to jenkins ? I seem to have same issue :(

Answer (score 8):

Bash sources `.bash_profile` only for login sessions, which a Jenkins process is not.

Put your PATH changes in `.bashrc`, instead.

See also the [bash manual on startup files.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add anything to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, you have to `source` it. So that added variables will be available to the `environment`. In your case, `source ~/.bash_profile` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The case could be because you launched the slave agent before making changes in Bash_profile. But Jenkins is still holding on to old values.  Relaunching the slave agent could fix it as it has fixed the same issue in my case as the env was showing old parameters in profile file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was reloading my tomcat server that was running Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can vim ~/.ssh/environment and add environment variables there.
You might need to permit user environment in ssh configuration

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Set PermitUserEnvironment to yes.
```

Reload configuration

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```